# Retreiving the real hostname of VMs under KVM using Virsh

Tags: kvm-virtualization

In KVM Support, `virsh list --all` lists all the domain name created and not the real host name of the VM. i.e it will list only the display name which will be specified during the creation of VMs.

However as very well known thing is, user can change the real hostname of the VM which is  under KVM, after the change is made the domain name which was specified during the creation remains the same.

`virsh list --all` lists the same domain name and not the real hostname of VM

So how can i retrieve the real hostname of the VM under KVM using `virsh` command?

Answer (score 2):

virsh man page says that hostname can be displayed with `virsh domhostname <domain>` command.
libvirt version 0.9.12 does not support this, but with libvirt version 1.2.1 this option is available.

Comment: Support for domhostname is dependent on the hypervisor. I do not think KVM supports it.

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you need to install QEMU Guest Agent in the KVM guest:

```
dnf install qemu-guest-agent # RPM-based
apt-get install qemu-guest-agent # APT-based
```

Then enable the service:

```
systemctl enable --now qemu-guest-agent.service
```

Finally, from the hypervisor you should be able to run `virsh guestinfo <domain>` and it will return something like this:

```
os.id               : rocky
os.name             : Rocky Linux
os.pretty-name      : Rocky Linux 8.7 (Green Obsidian)
os.version          : 8.7 (Green Obsidian)
os.version-id       : 8.7
os.machine          : x86_64
os.kernel-release   : 4.18.0-425.3.1.el8.x86_64
os.kernel-version   : #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 20:13:27 UTC 2022
hostname            : foo.dataacq.sh
```